Please recommend a tool that allows simple and direct modification of programs to prevent Internet connection
Please recommend a tool that allows simple and direct modification of programs to prevent Internet connection, such as:

Shell software or encryption software: I haven't found it yet.

Software packaging software: I know that Turbo Studio has a function called network | IP restrictions can prevent the built Internet connection. EXE file Turbo Studio Container Configuration (https://hub.turbo.net/docs/studio/working-with-turbo-studio/configuration#ip-restriction-settings), Vmware Thinapp has not found the parameter to block networking in the configuration file package.ini. r other feasible software solutions.



This doesn't modify the exe, but you can block it from the context menu with this

More please, recommend it!!

Thank you, but my usage scenario and requirement is to definitely achieve it by modifying the exe.
